# Buoyancy - Droplet of Oil in Water

Tags: velocity, buoyancy

If I place a droplet of oil, which is less dense than water, at the bottom of a glass of water, it should start to rise in the water due to the buoyant force.

Will the oil droplet start rising faster and faster in the water? Like a rock falling down a cliff, which increases its velocity as it falls? And, if so, is there something equivalent to terminal velocity for oil droplets in water?

Comment: *Will the oil droplet start rising faster and faster in the water?* yes // *is there something equivalent to terminal velocity for oil droplets in water?* yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like any other object moving in a fluid, an oil droplet is subject to drag from the fluid. The drag generally increases with velocity (the precise manner in which the drag increases with velocity depends on the Reynolds number), and so eventually the buoyant force is equal to the drag force and the oil droplet reaches a terminal velocity.

There is one more effect to consider: in addition to generally slowing down the droplet, the drag also exerts a dynamic pressure on the surface of the droplet. If the dynamic pressure at terminal velocity is stronger than the surface tension of the oil droplet, then the oil droplet is likely to break up. Otherwise, the droplet merely deforms as it rises.